# What is an idiomatic French expression for "(pine for) a taste of home"?

Tags: expressions

{Handing over a souvenir, I said}:

> Je me suis dit que **les saveurs maison** vous manquaient peut-être.

This was the only phrase that came to mind on the spot in conversation, probably influenced by similar, concise turns of phrase in English, Italian, and even in Japanese: "a taste of home", "il sapore di casa", "ふるさとの味" respectively.

The thing is that in German, on the other hand, you are likely to use a more explanatory phrase "etwas Leckerem aus der Heimat" with the meaning of "something delicious from your homeland".

I cannot seem to find a dictionary entry referring to "les saveurs maison" as an equivalent of "a taste of home", so I'm not sure if I can get away with such a concise expression (as is the case with English, Italian, and Japanese), or I need to express the idea in a more explanatory manner (as is the case with German).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*A priori* il n'y a pas d'expression toute faite équivalente. Pour *taste* le choix sera entre « saveur » et « goût ».
Pour *home* je ne pense pas que « maison » soit le meilleur choix.  Le mot est d'emploi plus restreint que l'anglais *home* et l'allemand *Heimat* qui tous les deux renvoient au foyer, et même à la terre natale.

Le choix sera probablement entre « pays », « terre natale » ou peut-être même « terroir » selon le contexte. « Chez soi/vous » peut aussi être une option selon la façon dont on tournera la phrase.

Quelques idées dont on peut mélanger les morceaux :

> Je me suis dit que vous seriez content de retrouver les bons goûts du terroir.
>
> Je me suis dit que les saveurs de votre terre natale / du pays devaient vous manquer.
>
> Je me suis dit que vous aimeriez retrouver le(s) bon(s) goût(s) de chez vous.

Comment: In german, "Heimat" does indeed cover a broader spectrum of "home"-related terms. Now I see that "maison" is too limited in scope to have the desired effect. Merci.

Answer (score 4):

This is definitely correct/understandable. This kind of direct association is possible in French. For example, the expression, "is this homemade ?" would be : "est-ce maison ?" or "est-ce fait maison ?". Which shows that your phrase, if not strictly correct (from an academic point of view), is far from being incorrect.

However, a more natural way of saying this would probably be:

> Je me suis dit que **les saveurs de chez vous** vous manquaient peut-être.

Reste que ce qui détermine grandement l'emploi de cette expression sera son contexte d'utilisation. S'il s'agit de l'employer dans un cadre informel, alors elle fera l'affaire, car mieux vaut éviter les tournures trop pompeuses, sans quoi vous arracherez un sourire (bienveillant mais moqueur quoiqu'on en dise) à votre interlocuteur francophone.

Comment: I would also say that "chez soi" is the best translation of "home". To be home - être chez soi. You can always emphasize by adding an article: to like one's own home - aimer son chez-soi. I would thus also think that "les saveurs de chez vous" is a good translation.

Comment: However pay attention to the fact that "bien de chez soi" has a xenophobic connotation.

Answer (score 2):

The adjective "maison" means "home-made", not "that feels like home".

The feeling you are talking about is "le mal du pays":

> Je me suis dit que vous aviez peut-être le mal du pays.

"avoir le mal du pays" means "to miss one's home".

Comment: Merci. Supposing that you're hooked on junk food and hasn't touched proper homemade dishes for quite a while, then can you say "les saveurs maison", as opposed to what you eat at restaurants?

Comment: It would be a weird formulation, since that's not the flavours that are home-made but the dishes. In a poetic context it would work, but not so much in casual conversation.

Comment: However for example if some friend in bringing a cake to your home and tell you "C'est un gâteau maison" it means it is home-made, maybe by this friend.